# Azure using ES6 with a Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, azure

I am using an Azure App service instance to deploy a NodeJS application. When I attempt to access the system I get a 500 error code. On inspected of the logs that I noticed that I am getting the following error message:

```
Unexpected token import
```

I realized this was because it was ES6 and needed to be ES5.

I did some further research and found out it can be compiled to es2015 using Babel.

I added the following to the package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js app.js"
   ...
```

It runs locally without any issues but when it is deployed via local GitHub to the Azure instance it says "Deployment Successful" but I noticed the following message when it is deploying:

```
Start script "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js app.js" 
from package.json is not found.
```

I still attempted to access the application but I still get the same error:

```
Unexpected token import
```

Is there some way to allow ES6 on an Azure App instance?

Comment: Have you added “babel” as dev dependency?

Comment: I’ve tried it with dev and main

Answer (score 0):

You can use esm to instead of babel

package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

and replace the start script in package.json as
"node -r esm server.js"

it works !!!!